# Exportasfixedformat breaking excel (excel to pdf)

Tags: vb.net, excel, pdf, pdf-conversion

I'm trying to use this Exportasfixedformat method to convert from .xls, to pdf.
It works, but its behavior is quite strange.

my excel is like this:

column 1 |column 2 |column 3 |column 4 |column 5 |column 6 |column 7 |column 8 |column 9

and the pdf is like this:

column 1 |column 2 |column 3 (in the first page)
column 4 |column 5 |column 6 (in the second page) and so on....

I tried both

```
WrkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, aPathFile)

WrkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, aPathFile, Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, True, False, 1, 1, False, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
```

I would like to display all columns on one page Any suggestions? Please help

I use Itextsharp.

Comment: I removed the [tag:itextsharp] tag. I don't see any reason why this question should be tagged as an iText-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
worksheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false
```

provided me all columns in one page.

Anyways Thanks a ton!! aucuparia, you made me look into Pagesetup properties.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExportAsFixedFormat` method uses the page setup (i.e. how the workbook appears when printed) to render the file.  To get all the columns on one page, set

```
WrkBook.WorkSheets("sheetname").PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

before exporting.  The (many) other properties of `PageSetup` will also affect the results.

Comment: That isn't helping. PageSetup seems to be a attribute or Excel.Worksheet and not Excel.WorkbookClass which is my thing. I tried with Worksheet but it went in vein. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  You need to set the `PageSetup` property on each sheet you're exporting.  I've edited the answer.  Obviously replace "sheetname" with the name of the appropriate sheet, or a number (sheets are indexed from 1), or use `for each ws in WrkBook.WorkSheets...Next` to loop through them all.